# Resetting users password in forms authentication asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-authentication

I'm Having a page in which all the user accounts are shown in a grid view.  I'm the admin and i want to change or reset the password of a particular user. How this can be done?
Password format is salt and using forms authentication.

Comment: Are you using asp.net membership ?

Comment: yup, nothing to do with Forms Auth. All depends on your membership system, be it the built in provider or a custom one.

Comment: @RPM1984: It has everything to do with FormsAUth as it have its own `ChangePassword` and `ResetPassword` methods provided OP is using ASP.NET MemberShip Provider.

Comment: @naveen - yes, *provided* their using ASP.NET Membership provider. Im using a custom, so both change/reset pw is done by my provider. Forms Auth only signs out/logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Change the available password in db with new password and send the new password to user. Request the user to change the password once the log in.